# This for loop displays only the last entry of the student record

Tags: python, python-3.x

when I create a number of instances in the student class
the display method only displays the last entry 
here is my code

```
class student:
    def __init__(self):
        self.usn= None
        self.name=None
        self.branch=None
        self.phno=None
    def read(self):
        self.usn=input("enter the  usn: ")
        self.name=input("enter the name: ")
        self.branch=input("enter the branch: ")
        self.phno=input("enter the phno: ")

    def display(self):
        print(f'\n{self.usn}  {self.name}  {self.branch}   {self.phno}\n')
print(f'\nusn %name branch phno\n')
n=int(input("enter number of students : "))
for i in range(n):
    emp=student()
    emp.read()
print("\nusn   name branch phno\n")

for i  in student():

    emp[i].display()
```

The read method works well,I am able to enter many student records
but I have an issue with the display method which only prints the last student record

so I tried to iterate the loop but ended up with an error

```
for i  in student():
    emp[i].display()
```

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

so how do I iterate to retrieve all the objects 
and get to display all the entered student records

Comment: All student's details are entered into same variables. When you entered second student's details, this replaced first student's details. Finally, what's left is what you entered last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same variable inside the for loop. on each iteration the last entered student get deleted and replaced with the new data. You should use an array (or any other suitable data structure for your use case) and add a new Student in the array on every iteration.

this code should work:

```py
arr = list()
for i in range(n):
    emp=student()
    emp.read()
    arr.append(emp)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a structure to hold all the objects of your class, for example, a list.
An empty list can be simply created with `emp = []`.
Then you can append your objects to the list with the method `append()`.
So you have:

```py
emp = [] #declare empty list
for i in range(n):
    emp.append(student())
    emp[i].read()
```

Then you can iterate directly over the list:

```py
for x in emp:
    x.display()
```

On each iteration, `x` will be the next object in the list

Answer (score 1):

With the answers given by other users,I got the right output I wanted
Here is the code

```
    class student:
    def __init__(self):
        self.usn= None
        self.name=None
        self.branch=None
        self.phno=None
    def read(self):
        self.usn=input("enter the  usn: ")
        self.name=input("enter the name: ")
        self.branch=input("enter the branch: ")
        self.phno=input("enter the phno: ")

    def display(self):
        print(f'\n{self.usn}  {self.name}  {self.branch}   {self.phno}\n')
n=int(input("enter number of students : "))
arr = list()
for i in range(n):
    emp=student()
    emp.read()
    arr.append(emp)
for x in arr:
    x.display()
```